# Delete comment parents in mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am using typegoose and type-graphql.
I have a `CommentModel` which has a `parentId` field that stores ObjectId of its parent comment.

**What do I want?**

I want to automate deletion of parents by using `pre` middleware. means when I delete a comment, I want it to delete all the comments that their `parentId` equals to targeted comment id.

**An example:**

So, when I delete comment 2, I expect the comment 1 will be deleted too.

```
comment: [
    {
        _id: 1,
        parentId: 2
    }, 
    {
        _id: 2,
        parentId: null
    }
]
```

but I can't.

**What did I do?**

this is my middleware:

```
@pre(/remove|delete/i, async function () {
    await CommentModel.deleteMany({ parentId: this._id })
})
export class Comment {
   ...
}

export const CommentModel = getModelForClass(Comment)
```

And this is how I delete

```
await CommentModel.findByIdAndDelete(ID_OF_COMMENT)
```

this operation will NEVER finish. and always show me the loading spinner.
What do you suggest? Am I doing it wrong? or there is a better approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I fixed it:

```
@post(/remove|delete/i, async function (comment: DocumentType<Comment> | null) {
    if (comment?._id) {
        const children = await CommentModel.find({ parentId: comment._id }).lean().exec()
        await CommentModel.deleteMany({ parentId: comment._id })
        if (children) {
            await Promise.all(children.map(child => child?._id && CommentModel.deleteMany({ parentId: child._id })))
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

every middelware have a next funxtion to continue change it like this:

```
@pre(/remove|delete/i, async function (next) {
await CommentModel.deleteMany({ parentId: this._id })
next();
})
```

Comment: No, I found out where the problem comes from.

Comment: deleteMany returns an object of `deletedCount` and also calls the hook with object: `{deletedCount: 1}` which doesnt have _id property and it calls the deleteMany with undefined _id. this made a loop. I fixed it by type checking. `if(this._id){}`